# Extracting Method Body from Java Source Code with Eclipse JDT Plugin

Tags: java

I am working on a project and need to extract the method signature,name,return value and the body of the method from the java source code using Eclipse JDT

I can extract the method name,signature and return value. However, I am unable to extract the method body.

Comment: are you extracting this information for what purpose? Java Comments?

Comment: I am going to analysis for two versions of a java project and find out the changes on those two project. Besides, I want to find out what factors (function name, incomming/outgoiong call .. etc )causes the changes on the two versions..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the JDT Java Model elements: IType, IMethod, ... The Java Model does not represent the whole source code structure. It only represents the same elements, that you also can see in the Outline view.

To go further, you need to switch to the [AST model](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html).

Comment: Is there any other option I can find out the method body as well as other criteria such as incomming call ,outgoing call, signature,return value,type etc..?

Comment: Thanks @Seelenvirtuose , I use the AST model and extract the method body and every things..

Comment: @Ahsan can you share the code snippet how you extracted the java method body? Thank you.